# Filter a List based on an array of conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I'm currently obtaining a set of data via an API and I display it as a table on a cshtml page

| Item A | Supplier | Size | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boxes | Walmart | Small | Cardboard |
| Boxes | Costco | Medium | Cardboard |
| Boxes | Walmart | Small | Plastic |
| Bags | Target | Big | Leather |
| Bags | Walmart | Big | Plastic |

and I have 3 dropdowns each one with a catalogue corresponding to each column of my table.

Each time one of the checkboxes on my dropdowns is clicked I have to filter the table. So far my process is calling again the API to get the data then pass the selected values to my controller as an array to start applying filters with this function

```
for (int filterPos = 0; filterPos < filterList.Count; filterPos++)
            {
                List<StockItemsModel> filtered = model;
                if (filterPos == 0)
                {
                    if (model.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Contains(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        tmp = filtered;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (model.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        tmp = filtered;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (model.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        tmp = filtered;
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tmp.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Contains(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        tmp = tmp.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (model.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Contains(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        foreach (StockItemsModel item in filtered)
                        {
                            tmp.Add(item);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (tmp.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        tmp = tmp.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (model.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        foreach (StockItemsModel item in filtered)
                        {
                            tmp.Add(item);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (tmp.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        tmp = tmp.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (model.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                    {
                        filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos)));
                        foreach (StockItemsModel item in filtered)
                        {
                            tmp.Add(item);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            model = tmp;

            return PartialView("_AddStockTable", model);
}
```

so far the first and second filters work all right, for example filtering [Plastic, Small] works like a charm and I get only two records, but for [Plastic,Small,Cardboard] then I get also two records instead of three.
Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong in the process?

Comment: What logic you want to use?AND or OR logic for filterList?

Comment: @YiyiYou According each diferent column works with an AND logic ex: size1 & supplier1 & material1. But also each column has OR logic ex size1 & (supplier1 or supplier2) & material1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But also each column has OR logic ex size1 & (supplier1 or supplier2) & material1

If so,for `[Plastic,Small,Cardboard]`,you will get two records.It means `Small&(Plastic or Cardboard)`,the result will be:

| Item A | Supplier | Size | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boxes | Walmart | Small | Cardboard |
| Boxes | Walmart | Small | Plastic |

You can also use the following code to filter the data.Split `filterList` to `SupplierfilterList`,`SizefilterList`,`MaterialfilterList`,and then filter the model with the lists.

```
List<string> SupplierfilterList = new List<string>();
            List<string> SizefilterList = new List<string>();
            List<string> MaterialfilterList = new List<string>();
            List<StockItemsModel> filtered = model;
            for (int filterPos = 0; filterPos < filterList.Count; filterPos++) {
                if (model.FindAll(e => e.Supplier.Contains(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                {
                    SupplierfilterList.Add(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos));
                    continue;
                }
                if (model.FindAll(e => e.Size.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                {
                    SizefilterList.Add(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos));
                    continue;
                }
                if (model.FindAll(e => e.Material.Equals(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos))).Count > 0)
                {
                    MaterialfilterList.Add(filterList.ElementAt(filterPos));
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (SupplierfilterList.Count > 0) {
                filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => new[] { e.Supplier }.Any(SupplierfilterList.Contains));
            }
            if (SizefilterList.Count > 0)
            {
                filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => new[] { e.Size }.Any(SizefilterList.Contains));
            }
            if (MaterialfilterList.Count > 0)
            {
                filtered = filtered.FindAll(e => new[] { e.Material }.Any(MaterialfilterList.Contains));
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the solution to the filtering issue